# How to resolve all npm dependencies in tree to single version

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, dependency-management

I am somewhat new to npm and I have been working on converting an existing build process to use grunt with npm package management. We have a number of internal components that we build our apps upon. This results in a dependency tree that can get fairly complex. As a simplified example, consider:

```
module-bcm@1.1.0
├─┬ module-help@1.0.8
│ └── module-translation@1.2.1
└─┬ module-validation@1.0.6
  └── module-translation@1.2.2
```

In the maven world the module-translation package would be resolved to a single version and the build system then knows which package to include into the app.

In npm, I'm finding that the full tree is created in the node_modules directory, following the method described [here, under the section: Cycles, Conflicts, and Folder Parsimony](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

1. Are there any tools out there to resolve to a single version?

   1. I prefer this approach so I can use glob patterns to include all the resolved dependencies into the app.
2. Is it a bad idea to have the system resolve to a single version in npm?

   1. Of course, this can result in incompatible versions between dependencies, but that beast is there whether the dependencies are resolved to a single version systematically or manually. Are there other potential issues?

There is a related question asked here, but with no answer: [npm nested dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679730/npm-nested-dependency-management).

Comment: You can use [`npm dedupe`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html) to reduce duplicates. But, whether it can reduce to a single version depends on the version ranges each dependent module has specified. They may not all align with a version in common and `npm` won't reduce to the point of possibly introducing breakage.

Comment: I played around with this and yes, it can shorten the tree, but only if all the versions are the same. I suppose the question really is regarding resolving multiple versions to a single one, which would inevitably have the potential of introducing breaking changes. You say that npm won't do this, are there any tools that would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm finding that this question doesn't quite make sense in the world of npm dependency management. Unlike tools such as maven, js can have multiple versions of the same package/artifact used at the same time.

My understanding is that using a tool such as browserify (or requirejs) it can handle the above situation where different versions of "module-translation" are needed. So really, there is no need to flatten the tree. Since flattening the tree could produce versioning conflicts, why do it if browserify can handle the multiple versions anyway?

Comment: A web app that wants to be as bandwidth efficient as possible by avoiding multiple versions by allowing the dev to force a single version for the project. Sure that could very well cause conflicts but it should still be an option available to the dev.

Comment: With different versions of the same package might be annoying if we have this kind of scenario:
- Classes in module-translation@1.2.1 are used in interfaces in module-help@1.0.8.
- Classes in module-translation@1.2.2 are used in interfaces in module-validation@1.0.6.
- Interfaces in module-help@1.0.8 and module-validation@1.0.6 are interacting in module-bcm@1.1.0.

Different versions of module-translation results in incompatible APIs, unless the semantic version is followed strictly in these package in this case.

Answer (score 0):

On a somewhat related note, `yarn` (it uses `npm` under the hood) offers an option to install all the dependencies with only one version per each package ([yarn install --flat](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-flat)), which effectively produces flat dependency tree.

If more granular control is needed, look into [selective dependency resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/).